# The choice of $\epsilon$ in the proofs of divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

To show that the sequence $a_n$ converges to some $l\in\mathbb{R}$, we need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a corresponding $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
m\geq N\Rightarrow |a_m-l|<\epsilon
$$
To show that a sequence diverges, we need to negate this definition. That is, the sequence $a_n$ diverges if for every $l\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a corresponding $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $m\geq N$ with $|a_m-l|\geq \epsilon$.

I have seen few proof of divergence. I understand the proofs structure but what I do not understand is that in the proofs of divergence, how do you come up with the choice of $\epsilon_0$? For example, in the prrof of divergence of $a_n=n$ or $a_n=(-1)^n$, $\epsilon_0=1$ is chosen; I need to know how does one choose this $\epsilon_0$?

Comment: You almost never choose $\epsilon_0$ in advance, but rather first perform some calculation, and then see that for that reason $|a_n-l|$ is larger than some positive number, which will become your $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: If convergence means that the sequence "settles down" and stays in small $\epsilon$ neighborhoods of a limit $\ell$, then of course divergence concerns the sequence failing to do so, and "jumping around" by some amounts exceeding the choice of $\epsilon$ you want to make.  So look at the behavior of the sequence with an eye to how much the values shift around, and pick $\epsilon$ small enough that there will be infinitely many such "jumps" in the tail of the sequence.

Comment: You choose $\epsilon_0$ small enough to make your proof as easy as possible. There are lots of 'right' choices available; if a particular value for $\epsilon_0$ gives a counterexample, then so does any smaller value of $\epsilon_0$. One could use the limit points of a sequence to classify which $\epsilon_0$ give counterexamples and which don't, but that's way more complicated than it needs to be -- analysis is all about realizing that lots of choices don't matter so you should pick anything that makes your life as easy as possible while still achieving your aims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually visualizing the graph of the sequence (if possible) is sufficient for finding the right $\epsilon_0$. For example, in $s_n = n$, you know that you can pick anything you want for $\epsilon_0$, because after a point $s_n$ passes that point and never comes back. However, if you've got something like $(-1)^n$, you don't want to pick $\epsilon_0 = 4$ for example, because you know that all of the terms will fit within that $\epsilon_0$. But picking any $\epsilon_0<1$ will work, because the graph will keep alternating between $\pm1$, that are at distance $2$.